# use @property in tow apps in django

Tags: django, properties

**user.models.py**

```
class user(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    wallet = models.ForeignKey(Wallet, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @property
    def full_name(self)
        return self.name + self.last_name
```

**wallet.models.py**

```
class wallet(models.Model):
     amount = models.IntegerField()
```

**wallet.admin.py**

```
class UserrInline(admin.TabularInline):
    list_display = ['full_name'] #but I can't use property in app user

class walletAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [UserrInline]

admin.site.register(wallet, walletAdmin)
```

i cant use property in tow apps in django

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a property, you access it by name, so a string of the name:

```
class UserrInline(admin.TabularInline):
    list_display = ['full_name']
```

It is however more readable and robust to work with an f-string:

```
class User(models.Model):
    # …

    @property
    def full_name(self):
        return f'{self.name} {self.last_name}'
```

---

> **Note**: Models in Django are written in *PascalCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`user`</s> to `User`.